# Must a non-simple graph have nodes of equal degrees?

Tags: graph-theory

If the graph is not simple, does it have to have two different nodes of equal degrees? Probably not, but I need a counterexample with at least **5 nodes and 10 edges**.

Comment: It took me 2 minutes of trial and error to add $5$ extra edges to a $5$-cycle to make the vertex degrees $2,3,4,5,6$.

Comment: Vertices $v,w,x,y,z$ and edges $vw,wx,xy,xy,yz,yz,zv,zv,zv,zv$. How many hours did you spend on this exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Take $5$ nodes. Attach $4$ self-loops with the first node, $3$ with the second, $2$ with the third, $1$ with the fourth, and keep the fifth one lonely.

Check that the degrees of all the nodes are different. Also, you have $5$ nodes and $10$ edges.